# How to render the view of specific models in ASP.NET MVC4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm learning ASP.NET MVC4, this in my first experience in Web development.

I'm dealing with a situation. In one of my controllers, I'm returning a `IEnumerable<BaseClass>` to a View.

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(Models);
    }

    // this static method is just for demo
    static List<BaseModel> Models()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Imagine now, that we have 6 concrete class in BaseModels.

```
public class ConcreteModel1 : BaseModel { .. }  // Must show view1
public class ConcreteModel2 : BaseModel { .. }  // Must show view2
public class ConcreteModel3 : BaseModel { .. }  // and so on..
public class ConcreteModel4 : BaseModel { .. }
public class ConcreteModel5 : BaseModel { .. }
public class ConcreteModel6 : BaseModel { .. }
```

When I want to display the data, each `ConcrenteModel` has its own `View`. As it's shown in the below image.

[image]

How can I accomplish this? If I wasn't very clear, please let me know
Thanks.

Comment: So you need a composite UI based on the concrete type of the model? Or in other words, you need to be able to display an unknown number of, say `modules`, based on the different concrete types?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud That's right, based on the different concrete types

Comment: Alright, I believe I've provided you with a solution that's as dynamic and generic as what you're looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a complete solution:

### Models

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
    public abstract class BaseModel
    {
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }

    public class ConcreteModel1 : BaseModel { }
    public class ConcreteModel2 : BaseModel { }
    public class ConcreteModel3 : BaseModel { }
}
```

### Composite View

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.List<MvcApplication1.Models.BaseModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CompositeView";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>
    CompositeView</h2>
@foreach (var model in Model)
{
    Html.RenderPartial(string.Format("_{0}", model.GetType().Name), model);
}
```

### Concrete Views

#### _ConcreteModel1.cshtml

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.ConcreteModel1

<h1>Concrete Model 1</h1>
@Model.Content
```

#### _ConcreteModel2.cshtml

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.ConcreteModel2

<h1>Concrete Model 2</h1>
@Model.Content
```

#### _ConcreteModel3.cshtml

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.ConcreteModel3

<h1>Concrete Model 3</h1>
@Model.Content
```

### Controller

```
public ActionResult CompositeView()
{
    List<BaseModel> model = new List<BaseModel>();
    model.Add(new ConcreteModel1() { Content = "This is model 1." });
    model.Add(new ConcreteModel2() { Content = "This is model 2." });
    model.Add(new ConcreteModel3() { Content = "This is model 3." });

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Does it eliminate the use of Linq joins in the action ?

Answer (score 3):

You can have a composite view for the `TestView` and then render partial views for each of the smaller views. To accomplish this the models for the smaller views will need to be available from the model passed to the composite view.

Something like this: (TestView.cshtml)

```
@model ParentViewModel

@Html.RenderPartial("View1", Model.SubModel1)
@Html.RenderPartial("View2", Model.SubModel2)
@Html.RenderPartial("View3", Model.SubModel3)
```

You then have separate views, like: (View1.cshtml)

```
@model SubViewModel1

<!-- Whatever -->
```

Comment: Though this is correct theoretically, reflection would need to be used if the layout is to be as dynamic as the OP stated. The OP *appears* to be specifically looking for a solution that will render them out of the list without regard for *knowing* what's *can* be in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I would actually create a custom model whose contents were your `IEnumerable<BaseModel>` that had its own built in methods for retrieving a specific model by type. That way you can render partial views and send into them the specific `ConcreteModel` typed properly. Maybe something like:

```
public class UltraModel
{
    // I recommend using an interface rather than a base class
    // to avoid potentially confusing types
    public IBaseModel Models { get; set; }

    public T getModelByType<T>()
    {
        return (T)Models.Where(x => x is T).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Then in your global view you can render partials with:

```
RenderPartial("ConcreteViewName", Model.getModelByType<ConcreteModel1>());
```

*Note: Treat the above as psuedo-code. It will likely need to be tweaked to work just right.*